# getting negative variance, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: statistics

I'm getting a negative variance and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Did I make a calculation error or am I just going about it all wrong?

Two pencils are selected at random from a box that contains 3 blue, 2 red, and 3 green pencils. Let X be the number of blue pencils (rows) and Y be the number of red pencils (columns) selected. The joint PMF is:

```
f(x,y)  0       1       2
0       3/28    3/14    1/28
1       9/28    3/14    0
2       3/28    0       0
```

(a) Find the conditional distribution of the number of blue pencils given the number of red pencils.

```
               Y
   g(x|y)   0     1     2
   0       1/5   1/2    1
X  1       3/5   1/2    0 
   2       1/5    0     0
```

(b) Find the conditional mean of the number of blue pencils given the number of red pencils is y.

$$E(X|y) = 1.5$$

(c) Find the conditional variance of the number of blue pencils given the number of red pencils is y.

$$E(X^2|y)=1.9$$
$$Var(X^2|y)=1.9-1.5^2=-0.35$$

Answer (score 1):

You are going about it wrong.  The conditional mean and variance shouldn't be constant: they will depend on $y$.  There will be one answer for $y=0$, another for $y=1$, another for $y=2$.